# .NET: Microservices, Hexagonal Architecture with lightweight DDD - how to avoid leaky abstraction without a major performance loss?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, hexagonal-architecture

So, I have a whole system built as microservices.On a service level, I'm utilizing Hexagonal Architecture with lightweight DDD (no events, aggregators etc.)

I have a service that fetches Users via their Tokens, and then I have to fetch their Permissions accordingly.

I'm trying to figure out how to fetch data via EF, without leaking the implementation details to the domain layer.

Approach A:
[image]

This allows me to lazyload Permissions onto Users after running the method, but since whole logic is contained in the domain - I'm leaking the implementation (usage of IQueryable).

Approach B:
[image]

This also leaks implementation, because I'm restricting domain to EF - If I used an in-memory database instead of EF - I wouldn't need this solution, and thus it's a bad solution.

Approach C:
[image]

This is the only solution that doesn't leak anything and allows me to easily plug the repository out of EF, and plug a text file, an in-memory database or anything really.

The only issue is - it eager-loads data, which will become a huge query if I use this approach for stuff like: Posts, Comments etc.

I'm clueless at this point, is there a 4th option?

Comment: Take off the `ToList()` call and it shouldn't eager load anymore.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, it won't load at all - it'll be an empty list of Permissions and I need that data

Comment: Well, that's odd.  Have you tried calling `ToList()` on the result of the GetUsersByTokens call?

Comment: If I do, I'm leaking implementation to the domain :D (and yes, the permissions was empty - perhaps lazyloading doesn't work?)

Comment: Uh, no.  ToList merely compels the query to execute.  It's just a test.  Remember, this is supposed to be a lazy query, so if you look at the output without enumerating it, you won't see anything.

Comment: I'll check, perhaps the only issue I'm actually having is disabled lazyloading (which might be a default)

Comment: Well, the ToList in your implementation guarantees that the query will be eager loaded.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've just checked - it was lazyloading issue. Could you post an answer telling me to enable LazyLoadingProxies? I'll approve it, so others save time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to use lazy-loading is by installing the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package and enabling it with a call to UseLazyLoadingProxies.

For example:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

Or when using AddDbContext:

```
.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy